# What is best displaying a long list of items

Tags: usability, lists

Hi in my app user can select an item in a long pre-defined list to add to the user owned list. The user's list therefore may have hundred of items. The user must be able to see what items are in his / her list and remove items from the list as well. The list works exactly like how you would compose an email on Google mail and add people the to recipient list. How can I effectively do this. Thanks.

Comment: " How can I effectively do this." Are you asking how to implement it or parameters for how to design it?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. By "do" I meant keep the long list visible to the user (so he / she knows what he / she owns and remove any if needed).

Answer (score 2):

It would help to see a bit more context about how this list is to be used in your UI, but I would consider the following:

1. A long list almost certainly shouldn't be displayed in one go, such as in a dropdown - https://lawsofux.com/millers-law.html
2. If the list is to be used in the same way as something like gmail addresses (small area of screen real estate), a control where you can `typeahead` to filter the records would be a sensible approach
3. If the list is to be used where more screen space is available, or your interface allows users to transition to another page, you could build a separate list page with the option to select or de-select rows. Perhaps with other controls such as filters, sorting and multi-select.